# When does initWithCoder get called?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, xcode, nscoder

This will load an array

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*) coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder: coder];
    if (self) {
        myArray=[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"myArray"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

What is the code that will call this function so that the array can be loaded?

Comment: Not that you have to retain the array to take ownership.

Answer (score 4):

The `initWithCoder:` methods are used for deserializing using [NSCoding protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), e.g. via [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/). For details see the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i), especially the [Encoding and Decoding Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE) section.

Answer (score 1):

As DarkDust said, it's called when a NSUnarchiver or a NSKeyedUnarchiver is used. However, this is not necessarily the own case. One could actually implement a custom NSCoder and according NSDecoder .. e.g. to encode/decode yaml etc...

The most common use case is when loading nib files, as those contents are archived.