# Objective-C how to call a method after self is initialized inside the object file?

Tags: objective-c, methods, self

Is there any way to know when a custom object is finished with being initialized from inside the object's file? Or let me rephrase the question, why can't I call any method inside this method?

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    //NSLog(@"initWithCoder inside CustomObject (subclass of UIView)");
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        //... initialization here


        [self visibleEmptyButton]; //why does this method never get called?


    }
    return self;
}
```

EDIT:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{



    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad inside CustomObject(subclass of UIView) is called"); //It never gets called
    [self viewDidLoad];
    //initialization here...


}
```

Comment: My guess is that you're initiating the view from a storyboard/xib. If so, the button probably doesn't exist yet. Try moving the method call to viewDidLoad instead...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741946/when-does-initwithcoder-get-called

Comment: @nick That is right that I am using xib to initialize this view. I tried it too, but the method never gets called...

Comment: Could you show how/where do you initiate the class?

Comment: viewDidLoad is not a UIViewMethod. It's a UIViewController method.

Comment: How are you creating your view?

Comment: If initWithCoder was called at all (and not any other init method) then [self visibleEmptyButton]; should be called in most cases (99+ %)

Comment: Calling `[self viewDidLoad];` within `viewDidLoad` will cause some ... stackoverflow (tätä) :)     Simply call `[super viewDidLoad];` instead.

Comment: @Herman No, it is possible, because UIView has no such method, only UIViewController. So I am going to custom a UIViewController, then own this custom UIView.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to call [self viewDidLoad] within viewDidLoad. It will just cause some sort of endless loop. Not really endless because it consumes some fractio of the call stack on every call. Give it a try.

Comment: @Herman I have tried, but the method never gets called. I will try other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If the class you are init-ing is a subclass of UIViewController) Changing and setting things in the screen should be done after the view is loaded. Try doing it in this method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self visibleEmptyButton];
    //Do the additional view altering here
}
```

If this method doesn't exist yet you can just add it to the .m file (no need to add it to the .h file).

Comment: In that case you could create a UIViewController instance and make that the owner of you UIView. That Controller will then get the above mentioned call.

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of you're edit you could simply move the call to the UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [TheInstanceOfYourViewClass visibleEmptyButton];
}
```

Also, to avoid making a whole bunch of small subview related methods public it often makes sense to create *one* method to handle the initial visual states.